# Junit5 using WebTestClient failing for Spring Function

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, junit5, spring-cloud-function, webtestclient

I have written a Spring Function and I am able to run junit to validate function. Howerver, if I am try to run junit to test same function as Http endpoint, below error is thrown.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 NOT_FOUND>
```

Function Bean looks as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RetryFunction {

    private final RetryExecutor retryExecutor;

    @Bean
    public Function<Message<Request>, Message<Response>> executeRetryJob() {
        return request -> {
            log.info("Received [request : {}]",request);
            retryExecutor.executeJob(request.getPayload());

            var response = Response.builder()
                    .message(request.getPayload().getName().concat("submitted successfully."))
                    .build();
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(response).build();
        };
    }
}

@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Request {
    private String name;
}


@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response {
    private String message;
}
```

Junit code which is failing looks like below:

```
@WebFluxTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RetryFunction.class)
class JobExecutionFunctionTest {

    @MockBean
    private RetryExecutor retryExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnSuccessResponseWithHttpStatus200() {

        var randomRequest = Request.builder().name(randomAlphanumericString(10)).build();
        var requestMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(randomRequest).build();

        var randomResponse = Response.builder()
                .response(randomRequest.getName().concat("submitted successfully."))
                .build();
        var expectedResponseMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(randomResponse).build();
        doNothing().when(retryExecutor).executeJob(randomRequest);

        webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/executeRetryJob")
                .body(Flux.just(requestMessage),Message.class)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(Message.class).isEqualTo(expectedResponseMessage);;
    }
}
```

On running above junit, below error is thrown

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 NOT_FOUND>

> POST /executeRetryJob
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Content-Type: [application/json]

[{"payload":{"job_name":"os2zazNuIm"},"headers":{"id":"69f63243-0c6f-c911-4b77-ee39cadf3f42","timestamp":1609417585159}}]

< 404 NOT_FOUND Not Found
< Content-Type: [application/json]
< Content-Length: [130]

{"timestamp":"2020-12-31T12:26:25.461+00:00","path":"/executeRetryJob","status":404,"error":"Not Found","requestId":"31d47bd8"}
```

Any suggestion why this error is coming?

Comment: HTTP 404 says the URL you're using in the JUnit test isn't correct.  Either the host or the port needs correction.

Comment: @duffymo I haven't changed server port in application.yml, hence it should run on localhost:8080. Does it need any kind of explicit configuration anywhere in junit ?

Comment: Junir doesn’t assume host or port. Spell it out.